# MongoDB grouping based on intervals

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to group my data based on number intervals in measurements. Can I do this with the aggregation framework, or with some map-reduce function?

I would like to group by color and whether the size is larger or smaller than 5. I would also want to add e.g. "medium" for sizes between 3 and 5.

I can group by size and color, but then each different size will have its own object.

I know this can be done by checking each different object's size by db.collection.find(), and then adding them according to my specifications, but that would be very slow.

Example:

```
Objects:
{
  color: "red",
  size:  2
}
{
  color: "red",
  size:  4
}
{
  color: "blue",
  size:  2
}
{
  color: "blue",
  size:  1
}
{
  color: "blue",
  size:  7
}
```

Output:

```
{
  _id: {
    color: "red",
    size: "small"
  }
  total size: 6
}
{
  _id: {
    color: "red",
    size: "large"
  }
  total size: 0
}
{
  _id: {
    color: "blue",
    size: small
  }
  total size: 3
}
{
  _id: {
    color: "blue",
    size: "large"
  }
  total size: 7
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy using [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "color": "$color",
            "size": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$lt": [ "$size", 3 ] },
                    "small",
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$lt": [ "$size", 6 ] },
                        "medium",
                        "large"
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "total_size": { "$sum": "$size" }
    }}
])
```

So just conditionally select the value in the grouping key based on the current value in the document and count.